# Функция выводит только последнюю строку

Tags: python

Имеется функция:

```
def stats(way, period):
    stats = json.load(open(f'{way}/stats.json', 'r', encoding = 'utf=8'))
    message = ''
    for i in stats[period].items():
        if "users" or "points" in i[0]:
            continue
        elif '№' in i[0]:
            message = f'{message}\nМаршрут {i[0]} - {i[1]}'
            print(message)
        else:
            c = {"all": f"Всего кругорейсов - {i[1]}", "pass" : f"Пассажиров перевезено - {i[1]}", "fine" : f'Штрафов выдано на сумму - {f"{i[1]:_} рублей".replace("_", ".")}', "award" : f'Премий выплачено/будет выплаченно на сумму - {f"{i[1]:_} рублей".replace("_", ".")}', "salary" : f'Зарплат выплаченно/будет выплаченно на сумму - {f"{i[1]:_} рублей".replace("_", ".")}'}[i[0]]
            message = f'{message}\n{c}'
    if period == "always":
        message = f'{message}\n\nКоличество сотрудников работавших в ЧАТП - {stats["always"]["users"]}'
    elif (period == "week" or period == "month") and way == "stats":
        print(stats)
        message = f'{message}\n\nНа данный момент в ЧАТП сотрудников - {stats["users_count"]}'
    return message
```

При попытке вывести результат, выводиться только последняя строка:

```
На данный момент в ЧАТП сотрудников - 7
```

В самом файле данные в таком формате:

```
{
   "always": {
      "all": 3,
      "№2": 3,
      "№50": 3,
      "№104": 3,
      "№114": 3,
      "№930": 3,
      "№434": 3,
      "pass": 3,
      "fine": 3,
      "award": 3,
      "salary": 3,
      "users": 7
   },
   "users_count": 7
}
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if "users" or "points" in i[0]:
    continue
```

это условие будет выполняться всегда и в цикле ничего полезного делаться не будет, потому что `"users"` - это для питона `True`

сделайте так:

```
if "users" in i[0] or "points" in i[0]:
```

если таких слов будет больше, можно сделать так:

```
if any(w in i[0] for w in ("users", "points", и т.д.))
```

**P.S.**

просто совет по коду - раз вы используете и ключ и значение по ключу, то читабельнее вместо

```
for i in stats[period].items():
```

сделать

```
for key, value in stats[period].items():
```